# Rule validation color_id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In `rules()` validation (In app/Http/Requests), is it possible to do the validation to check if `color_id` exist in the `colors` table table?

User select a color from the screen a submit. Each color has color Id (color_id)

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required'
        'color_id' => 'required' // and how to check if color_id is exist in db using rule?

    ];
}
```

Comment: Would it not be simpler to present the user with a list of allowed colours from your database rather than validate a million possible colours against a much smaller list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the exists validation function

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'color_id' => 'required|exists:colors',
    ];
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-exists

Comment: I am assuming `colors` is a model?

Comment: No, in this case `colors` is the table.